# Getting extra messages while executing a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apps

I'm facing a problem while creating a db trigger to raise an error message for oracle forms. Can you please help me out?

My code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER unsuccessful_attempts_lock
      BEFORE UPDATE of last_logon_date 
ON temp_user
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
CURSOR c_unsuccessful_attempts IS
  SELECT *
  FROM temp_unsuccessful_attempts
  WHERE user_id=:NEW.user_id; 
max_fails EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
   FOR r_unsuccessful_attempts IN c_unsuccessful_attempts
   LOOP
     IF(r_unsuccessful_attempts.locked ='Y') THEN
       RAISE max_fails;
     END IF;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN max_fails THEN
  FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME ('FND', 'FLEX-USER DEFINED ERROR');
  FND_MESSAGE.SET_TOKEN ('MSG', 'You have reached maximum failed logins. 
                This account has been locked temporarily. Please contact 
                your system administrator')
  FND_MESSAGE.RAISE_ERROR;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20400,'An error has occured.Please contact 
                 your system administrator'||SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
END unsuccessful_attempts_lock;
```

Once a user's account is locked, `temp_unsuccessful_attempts.locked` will get updated to 'Y' and he/se should not be able to login further. And `temp_user` is the table which gets updated when the user has a successful login.

So, once a user's acount is locked(`temp_unsuccessful_attempts.locked='Y'`) and then if he'll try to login with his correct password, tis trigger should get fire(upon updation of `temp_user` table) and form should give an error that his account is locked and should not progress further.

Message I'm getting is:

> ORACLE error -20001: ORA-20001: FLEX-USER DEFINED ERROR:N, MSG, You
>   have reached maximum failed logins. Please contact your system
>   administrator.
>
> ORA-06512: at "APPS.FND_MESSAGE",line 66
>
> ORA-06512: at "APPS.UNSUCCESSFUL_ATTEMPTS_LOCKS",line 38
>
> ORA-04088: error during excution of trigger
>   'APPS.UNSUCCESSFUL_ATTEMPTS_LOCKS' has been detected in
>   FND_SIGNON.NEW_SESSION.

My trigger is giving some extra message on my oracle apps screen. I just want to display

> You have reached maximum failed logins.Your account is locked temporarily.Please contact your helpdesk.

P.S: `FND_SIGNON.NEW_SESSION` is the procedure where temp_user.last_logon_date is getting updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here we use a function that get's the first error of the stack:

```
function strip_first_error(pcode in number, pmessage in varchar2) return varchar2 is
    --
    vpos number := instr(pmessage, 'ORA-', 5);
    --
  begin
    if pcode between 20000 and 20999 then
      if vpos != 0 then
        return( substr(substr(pmessage, 1, vpos -2 ),12) );
      else
        return( substr(pmessage,12) );
      end if;
    else
      return pmessage;
    end if;
  end;
```

And the usage is:

```
when others then
    message(strip_first_error(abs(sqlcode), sqlerrm));
```

**EDIT**

P.S.: this is the when others that handle errors in the call of your `update`. In your specific example should be:

```
begin
  update last_logon_date ...
exception
    when others then
      -- in forms you should use message or other function that display the error
      -- in pl/sql you should use dbms_output.put_line, for example.
      dbms_output.put_line( strip_first_error(abs(sqlcode) , sqlerrm) );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But sorry to say, it is giving me an error while compilation of function itself:
  

Errors for TRIGGER UNSUCCESSFUL_ATTEMPTS_LOCK:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
21/5     PLS-00201: identifier 'MESSAGE' must be declared
21/5     PL/SQL: Statement ignored


It seems this functionality will not work in a database trigger. Please help.

P.S: I'm creating this trigger in my database to raise a error message upon my application. I'm not modifying my application code.

Comment: @prashant1988 the sample with "message" is to use inside the forms, that have this function. If you use this in pl/sql, call just strip_first_error.

Comment: I've amended the same. Still i'm getting one error.

Errors for TRIGGER UNSUCCESSFUL_ATTEMPTS_LOCK:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
21/5     PLS-00221: 'STRIP_FIRST_ERROR' is not a procedure or is undefined
21/5     PL/SQL: Statement ignored

But I've already created and committed the function. 
-------------------------
Function created.

esp0002-SQL>commit;

Commit complete.

-------------------

Please advise.

Comment: Please check if you compile the function with the correct name. Using "desc" you see the function params?

Comment: yes it is there with the same name..
 DESC strip_first_error ..then I pressed F4 in TOAD and i can see the function there.

Comment: One more tip: you don't need commit when you are creating functions ;)

Comment: FYI..
@Sérgio Michels
"afiedt.buf" 16 lines, 414 characters 
  1  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strip_first_error(pcode IN NUMBER, pmessage IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARS
  2      
  3      vpos NUMBER := INSTR(pmessage, 'ORA-', 5);
  4      
  5    BEGIN
  6      IF pcode BETWEEN 20000 AND 20999 THEN
  7        IF vpos != 0 THEN
  8          RETURN( SUBSTR(SUBSTR(pmessage, 1, vpos -2 ),12) );
  9        ELSE
 10          RETURN( SUBSTR(pmessage,12) );
 11        END IF;
 12      ELSE
 13        RETURN pmessage;
 14      END IF;
 15*   END;
 16  /
Function created.
esp0002-SQL>commit;
Commit complete.

Comment: Ok, see my edit. If still not work, update your code, please.

Comment: no help! sorry to say..
dbms_output.put_line( strip_first_error(abs(sqlcode) , sqlerrm) );
 cannot display a message on a popup window in forms. 

And i cannot update  my app code.. :(

Comment: "cannot display a message on a popup window in forms" where are you running the dbms_output??

Comment: dbms_output I'm running on my database. I want a message to be displayed when a user logins on the oracle apps screen. My current trigger is doing so.. But it is giving some extra message. dbms_output will not work there.. i guess.. :/